# Stability LeapFrog method

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I have a system of ODE's $x''=Ax$ being $A$ a matrix. Denoting y=x', I obtain the first order system
$$
x'=y\\
y'=Ax.
$$
If we denote $x^n\approx x(t_n)$ and $y^n\approx y(t_n)$, and we apply the LeapFrog method
$$
w=x^n+\Delta ty^n/2\\
y^{n+1}=y^n+\Delta t(Aw)\\
x^{n+1}=w+\Delta t/2 y^{n+1}
$$
what can I say about its stability?
Thanks

Comment: Please do extend your previous questions like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586038/stability-of-leapfrog-method to avoid double posts.

Answer (score 1):

If $z= \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}$, we have
$$ z^{n+1} = \pmatrix{I + \frac{(\Delta t)^2}{2} A & \Delta t I + \frac{(\Delta t)^3}{4} A\cr
    \Delta t A & I + \frac{(\Delta t)^2}{2} A\cr} z^n $$
The eigenvalues of the matrix are $$1 + \frac{\lambda (\Delta t)^2}{2}  \pm \sqrt{\lambda}\Delta t \sqrt{1 + \frac{A (\Delta t)^2}{4}} $$
where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  If any of these has absolute value $> 1$, the method is unstable; if all have absolute value $< 1$, it is stable.

Comment: As the product of such an eigenvalue pair is $1$, it is almost unavoidable to get one outside the unit circle.

Comment: Unless they are complex with absolute value $1$.  So the best you can have is marginally stable.